# Drawing Swing components inside a Graphics object

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jframe

is there any way I can make a Java Graphics object (g) draw a swing component?
like a button or JLabel

something like g.drawJLabel ?

I'm trying to add a clickable text (Link) inside my graphic object but it's not possible to add a mouse listener to the graphics objects

Comment: Yes you can draw a Swing component (this is the way renderers work for JTable and JList etc.), but it will just draw an image of the component, it will not be clickable. If you want a clickable component, then use a real component and add it to the panel.

Comment: problem is if  I add a real component it will not show up inside the the object where i want  it to be rendered, any suggestions?

Comment: You have a coding problem. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your clickable text can be an JLabel with an mouselistener

```
 JLabel hyperlink=new JLabel("Click me");

 hyperlink.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
 @Override
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m)
 {
  hyperlink.setForeground(Color.blue);
 }

 @Override
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m)
{
 hyperlink.setForeground(Color.black);
}

 @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m)
  {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && 
    Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(hyperlink.getText())));
    }
   }
```

Make sure that your graphical object has some form of layout manager otherwise your text won't show up

Then inside your graphical objects which I assume all of them extends some form of JComponent you can add this text to your object and your text will still receive user input